# VeeValidate3: Custom validation always is true on submit

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vee-validate

I am using Vue.js 2 and VeeValidate3 to validate my form. This from is also making an axios call to check if the username is already in use. If so, obviously the validation needs to be `false`.

So far so good. I also see the error message `Dieser Name wird bereits verwendet` when I type in a username which is already in use.

However, if I see the error message and nevertheless click the submit button, the error message disappears and I can see the message `Submit submitCompleteNormalRegistrationForm` which gets printed when the form gets submitted.

The question is, why does the form get submitted also there is an validation error with the name? What I am doing wrong?

Also, how can I set the validation for the name to `true` when the name is not in use?

This is my code so far:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <ValidationObserver ref="completeNormalRegistrationForm" v-slot="{ passes }" class="flex-column flex-grow-1 d-flex w-100">
            <form @submit.prevent="passes(submitCompleteNormalRegistrationForm)" id="completeNormalRegistrationForm" class="flex-column flex-grow-1 d-flex w-100">
                <div class="backButtonWrapper text-left">
                    <i id="backButtonRegistrationForm" @click="showLoginForm" class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-left"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="form-wrapper margin-auto w-100">
                    <p class="rubik-bold" style="font-size: 1rem;">Registrieren</p>
                    <ValidationProvider vid="name" name="Nutzername" rules="required|alpha_dash" v-slot="{ errors }">
                        <input @keyup="completeNormalRegistrationFormUsernameExists" class="form-control search-username" v-model="registerForm.name" type="text" placeholder="Username">
                        <span v-if="errors[0]" class="username-invalid-span">{{ errors[0] }}</span>
                    </ValidationProvider>
                    <ValidationProvider vid="email" name="E-Mail" rules="required|email" v-slot="{ errors }">
                        <input class="form-control search-email" v-model="registerForm.email" type="email" placeholder="E-Mail">
                        <span v-if="errors[0]" class="email-invalid-span">{{ errors[0] }}</span>
                    </ValidationProvider>
                    <ValidationProvider vid="confirmation" name="Passwort" v-slot="{ errors }">
                        <input class="form-control" v-model="registerForm.password" type="password" placeholder="Passwort">
                        <span v-if="errors[0]" class="password-invalid-span">{{ errors[0] }}</span>
                    </ValidationProvider>
                    <ValidationProvider rules="confirmed:confirmation" name="Passwort" v-slot="{ errors }">
                        <input class="form-control" v-model="registerForm.passwordConfirmation" type="password" placeholder="Passwort wiederholen">
                        <span v-if="errors[0]" class="password-invalid-span">{{ errors[0] }}</span>
                    </ValidationProvider>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-big big-letter-spacing text-uppercase rubik-bold login">Anmelden</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </ValidationObserver>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "NavbarAction",
        data() {
            return {
                registerForm: {
                    name: '',
                    email: '',
                    password: '',
                    passwordConfirmation: '',
                    termsAndConditions: false,
                },
            }
        },
        methods: {
            async completeNormalRegistrationFormUsernameExists() {
                const nameValid = await this.usernameExists(this.registerForm.name);

                if (nameValid) {
                    this.$refs.completeNormalRegistrationForm.setErrors({name: 'Dieser Name wird bereits verwendet'});
                } else {
                    console.log('Set name is NOT in use!');
                }
            },
            async usernameExists(name){
                return await axios.post(window.routes.usernameExists, {value: name})
                    .then(r => {
                        return r.data;
                    });
            },
            submitCompleteNormalRegistrationForm(){
                console.log('Submit submitCompleteNormalRegistrationForm');
                console.log(this);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**UPDATE** (working with custom rule now):

```
extend('unique-email', (value) => {
    return axios.post(this.routes.emailExists, { value: value })
        .then((r) => {

            // If email exists, axios response is true
            if(r.data){
                return {
                    valid: false,
                    data: { message: 'E-Mail wird bereits genutzt' }
                };
            }else{
                return {
                    valid: true,
                };
            }
        }, (err) => {
            return {
                valid: false,
                data: { message: 'E-Mail wird bereits genutzt' }
            };
        })
    },
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to express your email validator as a vee-validate rule instead of trying to do it yourself on keyup.  One of the many undocumented things in vee-validate is that if you return a promise as the result of a validation, vee-validate will handle it correctly, waiting to get the result before allowing validation to pass.

Here's an example to get you started:

```
 mounted() {
   extend('unique-email', (value) => {
     return this.usernameExists(value)
     .then((res) => {
      return {
        valid: true,
      };
    }, (err) => {
      this.$refs.completeNormalRegistrationForm.setErrors({
         name: ['Username already registered']
      });
    })
    }, {
     immediate: false
   })
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I am currently at this point too. My problem at the moment is to set the error message correct. Can I also add a custom message to the rule itself instead of working with the `$ref` like you do it?

Comment: Also, whats `immediate`?

Comment: I have added my rule where I am stuck right now to my question above!

Comment: I believe `setErrors` is the only way they allow you to do this...  See [here](https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/advanced/server-side-validation.html#setting-errors-manually).

Comment: Alright, thank you... But can you tell me what immediate does? I have read the documentation but I don't get it...

Comment: immediate means that it will be validated on creation, so if the input is required but empty, it will immediately show the error messages

Comment: So, if I set `immediate` to `true`, it will `immediately` show the error message without having touched the input field?

Comment: in this case it will immediately trigger your ajax function (with whatever the initial value of the input is)

Comment: Thank! I have now accomplished what I want. Also using custom error messages without `$refs`. Checkout my own answer to my question! :)

Answer (score 0):

this is front-end validation. The only thing you can do is disable the button when the form is invalid. There is nothing preventing a smart kid trying to submit a form anyway. The true validation should be serverside.

something like:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-big big-letter-spacing text-uppercase rubik-bold login" :disabled="passes(submitCompleteNormalRegistrationForm)">Anmelden</button>
```

Comment: There is also a validation server-side. But I don't want to to an `axios` for every keypress... This is just to limit the amount of `axios` requests and show the errors right away to the user!

Answer (score 0):

Finally also found a way to set custom error messages without using `$refs`:

```
extend('unique-email', (value) => {
    return axios.post(window.laravel.emailExists, { value: value })
        .then((r) => {

            // If email exists, axios response is true
            if(r.data){
                return "E-Mail wird bereits genutzt";
            }else{
                return true;
            }
        }, (err) => {
            return "E-Mail wird bereits genutzt";
        })
    },
);
```